# How to insert multiple items from a cart into a table?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

This cart code takes multiple items from the shop page and displays them perfectly on this cart page.

I'm wondering how do I transport these cart variables into a table called orders.

I am stuck figuring out how to input a single instance of data into an orders table for some reason - if I can figure out this, then it should be easy how to input multiple records at once.

I think this is on the right track, I've echoed the below variables. But it only echoes out the last thing in the cart.

```
$name = $product['name'];
$quantity = $product['quantity'];
$productprice = $product['price']
```

I was testing how to input this string by inserting dummy data from order-process.php, which checks if a submit button is processed on cart.php.

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product):
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
<td>$ <?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
<td>$ <?php echo number_format($product['quantity'] *
$product['price'], 2); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
echo $name;
echo $quantity;
echo $total;

$query = "insert into products values('$name','$quantity',
'$total')";
$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>

<form method="POST" action="order-process.php" name = "submit "
value = "submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();
require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
if(isset($_post['submit']))
{
$SQL = "INSERT INTO orders (name, quantity, total) VALUES
('abc','10', '75')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
?>
```

I'd lke to learn how to insert dummythis dummy data, 
Ideally I would like to figure out how to extract the cart variables from cart.php and multiple insert rows for whatever the user has in that cart.

Comment: Use `foreach` to insert multiple data's

Comment: Thing is I have no idea how to do that, I got this as a template to learn php from. My main issue is that I can't insert a fake string into the database using order-process.php. If I can insert one row, I would attempt a for-each loop.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions together. They can't be used with each other, and `mysql_*` no longer exists in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to php, but I'm sure this is close enough to an answer as I can come up with.

You don't need two php files for processing cart items, you can insert items into a products table on the same page as the cart.php. The next step would be to place this insert statement inside a for-loop for the variables from that cart to place every item in that cart into the products table.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$SQL = "INSERT INTO orders (name, quantity, total, orderdate) VALUES ('abcdef', '100', '715',  NOW())";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $SQL);
}
```

?>